# "Clamp" barycentric coordinates?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, projection, barycentric-coordinates

Let's begin with something we know how to do. Given a point in 2D, one can project it to a segment by projecting the point onto the line containing the segment.

You do this by doing $s = (p - o)\cdot v$. where $p,o,v$ are the point, the origin of the line and the line direction with length equal to the segment. Doing this will produce the weighted signed distance of the projection onto the line. So then if you clamp that distance between 0 and 1. You know that  $s * v + o$ is the shortest distance from the line to the point.

I am trying to do the same for a point projected onto a triangle in 3d.

After projecting the point onto the plane defined by the triangle, I want to clamp the barycentric coordinates such that the resulting barycentric coordinates match the projection. Or alternatively I want to project the point onto it's closest point on the triangle.

Comment: A point outside a given reference triangle have one or two negative values in the triple of barycentric coordinates. If you wish to project onto the plane of the triangle, it is simple enough using the normal vector to the plane, which can be read off from the equation of the plane. Once one has the projection point, there are standard ways to obtain its barycentric coordinates w.r.t your given reference triangle. I don't know of any simple way to do all this given the point in space and the triangle.

Comment: I am not trying to just get the barycentric coordinates, I am trying to clamp them such that the resulting barycentric coordinates wield the projection of the point onto the triangle.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "clamp them" in this case.

Comment: @coffeemath It's trying to extend the line projection clamping I mentioned in the question. If the projection onto the plane lies outside the triangle, then you want to find the set of barycentric coordinates for the closest point in the triangle to the original point. Like on the line.

Comment: How to find whether the projection is outside the triangle *without* first finding the barycentric coordinates, and seeing if one or more is negative? [I still don't know what your verb "clamping" here means.]

Comment: I did not say you cannot find the bary coords, if you follow the line analogy, you first find the parametric coords of the line before clamping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142317/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-makogan).